# Delay Needed with Xcode UITest with iPhone 6s Plus Simulator but not iPhone 6s

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, xcode-ui-testing

Here's a synopsis of my UI Test:

```
func testMyUI() {
    self.app = XCUIApplication()

    //self.delay(forSecondsDuration: 1)
    let alerts = self.app.tables.staticTexts["Alerts"]
    self.waitForElement(alerts)
    alerts.tap()

    let customMessage = self.app.buttons["Custom Message"]
    self.waitForElement(customMessage)
    customMessage.tap()

    <snip>
}

func waitForElement(element:XCUIElement, toBeOnScreen onScreen:Bool=true) {
    var predicate:NSPredicate

    if onScreen {
        predicate = NSPredicate(format: "exists == true")
    }
    else {
        predicate = NSPredicate(format: "exists != true")
    }

    expectationForPredicate(predicate, evaluatedWithObject: element, handler: nil)
    waitForExpectationsWithTimeout(self.timeOutDuration, handler: nil)
}
```

This works (test passes) when I'm using an iPhone 6s simulator with iOS9.3, but with an iPhone 6s Plus simulator (also iOS9.3), I find it necessary to impose a slight delay after the `self.app = XCUIApplication()` line. Without the delay with the iPhone 6s Plus, the first `waitForElement` and `tap` doesn't actually do its job. It seems like this first tap occurs too early.
I'm using Xcode 7.3.1.
Thoughts?

Comment: It's a bug. I'm impressed that you were able to get the tap to work at all in Xcode 7.3.1! Basically my experience is that in Xcode 7.3.1, UI testing is totally broken. It's fixed in Xcode 8, though.

Comment: Thanks for the note! One more reason for me to shift to Xcode8. Xcode8 beta 1 was a bad puppy in converting my code to Swift 3 through. Haven't tried beta 2.

Comment: You're not required to accept the conversion. You should, though. It's the future and it's here. :)

Comment: By the way, I'm very impressed with your solution to this issue.

Comment: Thanks! Not quite sure what's impressive about it though :).